# writing and reading variable from a file in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to store a variable in a file so it can called upon on a long term basis.

In my example below the final echo command doesn't return the variable, however if I run the script a second time the variable is declared with the value from the first run. If i don't store the variable in a file it works fine, so why would the order of operation be different when storing it in a file?

```
PROJECT_NAME=$(cat "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME")

read -p "Enter the Project Name: "
echo ${REPLY} > "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME"
echo "The Project Name is ${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Comment: Did you just miss to assign the name to `PROJECT_NAME` after reading it via `read`?

Answer (score 0):

Your script works well, but **you made a mistake with the order of the instructions**.
Each time you create the `$PROJECT_NAME` variable, it is not yet overwritten by the `read -p` command.
Therefore, you need to get data from the file after you have written to it.
As follows:

```bash
# Ask what to write to a file
read -p "Enter the Project Name: "
# 1st, write to the file 
echo ${REPLY} > "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME"
# 2nd, get fresh data from the file  - creating variable $PROJECT_NAME
# "2>/dev/null" - will hide the error if the file, for example, doesn't exist 
PROJECT_NAME=$(cat "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME" 2>/dev/null)
# 3rd, output the fresh (latest) data 
echo "The Project Name is ${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Comment: Also, it would be sensible to test for file existance before asking for the project name.

Comment: @WolfgangLorenz In this order, the file `PROJECT_NAME` will always be created or overwritten. But according to previous instructions, I specified `2>/dev/null` to ignore this point.

Comment: That's not what I meant. It seems to me, the script should ask only for a project name, if none yet exists. Therefor something like `[ -f "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME" ] || { read -p "Enter the Project Name: "; echo ${REPLY} > "$(dirname "$0")/PROJECT_NAME"; }` would make sense to me. It wasn't specifically asked for in the question, though.